# allocating view controller the right way

Tags: macos, viewcontroller, alloc

i am trying to archiv something really simple.

I add a property for a NSScrollView in my ViewController header file called PanelController:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet NSScrollView *listurls_fld;
```

I add the ViewController.h file to my NSObject Interface called "qhandler.h"

```
#import "handler.h"
#import "PanelController.h"
```

i have a +(void) function inside the qhandler.m ->

```
+ (void)do_handle:(NSDictionary *)response
{
    PanelController *MyView=[[PanelController alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"add moo");
    [MyView.listurls_fld setStringValue:@"moo"];
}
```

which doesn't work...

It does neither work with setAlphaValue or whatever, i guess it's because i am allocating a new instance of PanelController, but as a matter of fact, I tried to change the main instance.

I know it's basic but i have enormous problems using IBOutlets from a viewcontroller, inside an external obj-c file.

Thanks,
john

Comment: Does the NSLog get called? You definitely don't want to create a new `PanelController` and operate on that, since it won't do what you need.   How do you put your PanelController into a window?

Answer (score 0):

ViewController.h

`id mainDelegate;`

ViewController.m
in viewDidLoad oder what function ever triggers after load:

`mainDelegate=self;`

so i can use `[mainDelegate ...:..];` in every file..